# onSubmit handler executes in jsfiddle, but not in my development environment

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, jsfiddle

My end goal with this code is that I want the data entered into the text field to be logged to the console when the button is pressed, but the onSubmit handler isn't executed in my development environment (by the way, my environment includes a development server set up using create-react-app).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {input: undefined}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" marginTop="200px">
        <div className="App-header">
          <h2>Timestamp Microservice</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          Converts a Unix timestamp (2365145258) to a natural language date (December 16, 2016) and vice versa.
        </p>
        <form>    
          <input type="text" onChange={(event) => this.setState({input: event.target.value})}/> <br/>
          <input type="submit" onSubmit={() => console.log(this.state.input)} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

However, the code works just fine in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/swapnil95/k0jpruyu/2/

Any responses would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: can you link your packages.json

Comment: `onSubmit` belongs on `<form>`, not `<input>`.

Comment: @ffxsam: problem still occurs when cut and paste onSubmit to <form>

Comment: The code looks fine other than that, hard to say what the problem is.

Comment: Though I would change that input submit to `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`

Comment: It is hard to say. Perhaps test the code by using create-react-app to replicate my environment?

Comment: See my answer below. You're also missing `super(props)`. It's important to pass the props in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need the form tag. If you have it the page is going to reload, but you're storing the values in the state with the onChange event on the input. Basically all the button needs to do is output the value to the console.

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="App-header">
      <h2>Timestamp Microservice</h2>
    </div>
    <p className="App-intro">
      Converts a Unix timestamp (2365145258) to a natural language date (December 16, 2016) and vice versa.
    </p>

      <input type="text" onChange={(event) => this.setState({input: event.target.value})}/> <br/>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(this.state.input)}> Submit </button>

  </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Wow, the solution is so simple. I just didn't understand the full semantics of <form>. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @srpalo no problem. happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The below should work:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {input: undefined};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" marginTop="200px">
        <div className="App-header">
          <h2>Timestamp Microservice</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          Converts a Unix timestamp (2365145258) to a natural language date (December 16, 2016) and vice versa.
        </p>
        <form onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); console.log(this.state.input) }}>    
          <input type="text" onChange={(event) => this.setState({input: event.target.value})}/> <br/>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```